# Vulkan macOS Instance failed to load

Tags: macos, glfw, vulkan, moltenvk

I'm following the [vulkan tutorial to create an instance](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Instance) on macOS. I've diverged slightly in that I'm using Clion and thus CMake, rather than XCode. When I try to run the program, I cannot create a Vulkan instance and the process exits with an error.

I've checked and Vulkan is supported by my GLFW library (3.3, installed with homebrew `--HEAD` flag).

My code:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

class HelloTriangleApplication {
public:
    void run() {
        initWindow();
        initVulkan();
        mainLoop();
        cleanup();
    }

private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
    VkInstance instance;

    void initWindow() {
        glfwInit();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    void initVulkan() {
        if(glfwVulkanSupported()) {
            std::cout << "Vulkan supported";
            createInstance();
        }
    }

    void mainLoop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    void cleanup() {
        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);

        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        glfwTerminate();
    }

    void createInstance() {
        VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
        appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
        appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
        appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
        appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
        appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

        VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
        createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
        createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

        uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
        const char** glfwExtensions;
        glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

        createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionCount;
        createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;

        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;

        if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create instance!");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    HelloTriangleApplication app;

    try {
        app.run();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(vulkantutorial)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(vulkantutorial main.cpp)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Vulkan::Vulkan)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLM REQUIRED glm)
include_directories(${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

In my CLion settings, I've defined the following environment variables:

- `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `VK_LAYER_PATH`
- `VK_ICD_FILENAMES`
- `VULKAN_SDK`

All but `VULKAN_SDK` were required to get `vulkaninfo`:

```
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.114



Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions     count = 8
        VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  9
        VK_EXT_debug_utils                  : extension revision  1
        VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace         : extension revision  4
        VK_KHR_device_group_creation        : extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2    : extension revision  1
        VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
        VK_MVK_macos_surface                : extension revision  2
Layers: count = 0
=======
Presentable Surfaces:
=====================
GPU id       : 0 (Intel(R) Iris(TM) Plus Graphics 655)
Surface type : VK_MVK_macos_surface
Formats:                count = 32
        B8G8R8A8_UNORM
...
```

Can anyone shed some light and help?

Comment: I have had a play with Vulkan on macOS and found it non-trivial to get moltenVK working.  I don't see why you need `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all as any required `.dylib`s should be copied into the app bundle.  You definitely need a custom `icd.d` file set-up in the app bundle `Resources` folder and have it set to find the molten VK dylib (the relative path reference in that file is from the file itself and not the main executable).  You only need to set `$VK_LAYER_PATH` during development in order to load the validation layers and you will be to have app sandboxing off.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that although I set the environment variables in CLion `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake -> Environment`, these are not passed through to the run configuration.

This is interesting, because they seem to be partially registered - I made a typo in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and got `dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_LIBRARY` for my troubles.

Setting the environment variables explicitly in the run configuration solved the problem (and also highlighted an error in my layer path). Although, would I be correct in thinking these should be passed down through CMake?